# Is our sites title justified?

Tags: discussion, scope

Wikipedia on [Physical Fitness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_fitness):

> **Physical fitness** comprises two related concepts: general fitness (a state of health and well-being), and specific fitness (a task-oriented definition based on the ability to perform specific aspects of sports or occupations). Physical fitness is generally achieved through correct nutrition, exercise, hygiene and rest.

- **Nutrition**: on topic, only in combination with exercise or achieving physical goals (eg fat loss diet)
- **Exercise**: on topic
- **Hygiene**: off topic
- **Rest**: on topic, only in combination with exercise

I don't want to make this sound as a suggestive question, I know that Wikipedia is no authority in defining expressions, but I still wonder if we are close enough to that or another definition (if you got another, please share).

So, do you think our sites title is justified?

Comment: I fear you're a little late to this particular party. Anyway I'm not getting involved in this discussion again

Comment: I think the scope of the site is good as it is, I don't have the intention to change it. What I ask myself is how do we communicate this to new people? (namely why the regularly occurring questions about sleep and nutrition are off topic)

Comment: @Informaficker That's the reason why we have the [faq] page and (to an extent) the about page. We had a _long_ discussion regarding our scope, the title of our site, and many suggestions and ideas for both those subjects. If you dig through the more historical meta posts (and also partly chat), you will certainly see what was going on back then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is justified. The scope and name of this site was defined and redefined and debated endlessly until no one wanted to talk about it anymore. The term "Physicial Fitness" is completely workable and widely understood, even if the name doesn't necessarily adhere to the most pedantic definition or adhere to every last concept it encompasses.

Physical Fitness SE does not encompass ***all*** nutrition topics, for example — much as Cooking SE doesn't allow recipe requests; Gaming SE doesn't allow video game recommendations; Home Improvement doesn't talk about building codes. It's what works for the community.

We're making a bunch of changes to how off topic questions are handled, primarily to make it an easier and gentler experiences when users run up against these subtleties. The site name simply needs to get them into the right *neighborhood*. It's the faq and the questions asked that actually defines the scope, and we're always trying to make it easier for the community to help self-moderate and guide users to where they need to be.